# Extract text from string in hive with regexp_extract

Tags: regex, string, hive, extract, hiveql

in my example how to extract from column even_list the number between '705=' and the next comma?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please show your sample data and desired result as text in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `split` in hive.
First of all we will split the data using `705=` as separator.
Then use split again to separate by comma. This gives me desired result.

```
select  split(split('123705=35,4,6752,56','705=')[1],',')[0] col 
output
35
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using regexp:

```
select regexp_extract(event_list,'705=([0-9.]+)',1)
```

Or you can use more strict regexp with commas `',705=([0-9.]+),'`